# Direct proof for $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{CP}_{1}}(-2) \cong T^{*}\mathbb{CP}_{1}$

Tags: complex-geometry, holomorphic-bundles, line-bundles

Recall the holomporphic line boundle $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{CP}_{1}}(-2):=  \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{CP}_{1}}(-1) \otimes
\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{CP}_{1}}(-1)$ where $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{CP}_{1}}(-1)$ is the "tautological line bundle" of $\mathbb{CP}_{1}$ , defined as $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{CP}_{1}}(-1) :=\{ \left( [z_0 ,z_1],(z_0 ,z_1) \right) \in \mathbb{CP}_{1}\times \mathbb{C}^{2}\setminus\{0\}   \} $. 
Also $T^{*}\mathbb{CP}_{1}$ would be the holomorphic cotangent bundle of $\mathbb{CP}_{1}$.

Someone may know from invariants of the line bundles (degree, first Chern class, Euler class, .etc) that the bundles  $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{CP}_{1}}(-2)$  and $T^{*}\mathbb{CP}_{1}$ are Isomorph (as smooth complex bundles).

I actually don't have a solid background on complex or algebraic geometry. I am looking for a directly writable Isomorphism map between these two line bundles that would be a holomorphic map between the total spaces (it should preserve the holomorphic structure too)

Terminology problem: what should I call this kind of isomorphism?

one possible approach that I have in mind :

both $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{CP}_{1}}(-2)$  and $T^{*}\mathbb{CP}_{1}$ can be regarded as Blow-up of $\mathbb{C}^{2}/\mathbb{Z}_2$ at the origin and we have a nice description of the Blow-down map in both cases:
$$\pi : \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{CP}_{1}}(-2) \mapsto \mathbb{C}^{2}/\mathbb{Z}_2  $$
$$\pi : \left( [z_0 ,z_1],\lambda^{2}(z_0 ,z_1)^2 \right) \mapsto \lambda(z_1,z_2) $$
and in [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2235762/resolution-of-quadric-cone-in-mathbbc3-is-biholomorphic-to-textt-ast/2235913#2235913) someone have described $T^{*}\mathbb{CP}_{1}$  as a resolution of $\mathbb{C}^{2}/\mathbb{Z}_2$.
 So, somebody may trace any line from one of these spaces to $\mathbb{C}^{2}/\mathbb{Z}_2$ and to the other one to find the isomorphism. but I can't figure out how exactly $T^{*}\mathbb{CP}_{1}$ and the blow-down map $T^{*}\mathbb{CP}_{1} \mapsto \mathbb{C}^{2}/\mathbb{Z}_2$ are described in the [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2235762/resolution-of-quadric-cone-in-mathbbc3-is-biholomorphic-to-textt-ast/2235913#2235913). Also, I guess my approach is overcomplicating a simple problem and someone may write the isomorphic map directly without thinking of these blow-downs.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: First, your definition of the tautological line bundle has a typo in it (no "$/0$", by which you mean "$\setminus 0$" anyhow). I would suggest considering the section $dz$ of $T^*\Bbb P^1\big|_{\Bbb C}$. Here by $\Bbb C$ I mean the subset $z_0\ne 0$. What happens to this section at the point at infinity, i.e., at the point $[0,1]$?

Comment: @TedShifrin Thanks for your comment, I have corrected the typo. What I understand from the hint you gave is to compare the trivialization of the bundles with each other. for $T^{*}\mathbb{CP}_1$ I fund the trivialization $-1/z^{2}$ that makes sense but for $\mathcal{O}(-2)$ I fund $1/z^2$! I think the sign problem has come from a problem in getting a correct trivialization for $\mathcal{O}(-2)$. Does the local map $\mathcal{O}(-2)|_{z_{0}\neq 0} \mapsto \mathbb{C}^{2}$ as $[z_0,z_1] (z_0,z_1)^{2}\mapsto (z_1/z_0 , z_{0}^{2})$ makes sense?

Comment: The sign is irrelevant. It's the order of zero or pole that matters. $dz$ as a $1$-form on $\Bbb P^1$ has a pole of order $2$ at $\infty$.